# Cannot find Alfresco Repository on this server. Does this application have cross-context permissions?)

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

After installing the Alfresco WAR's I'm getting the error message in the browser after startup: "Cannot find Alfresco Repository on this server. (Does this application have access to alfresco-global.properties? Does this application have cross-context permissions?)"

```
09-Sep-2020 11:13:55.768 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
09-Sep-2020 11:13:55.769 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
09-Sep-2020 11:13:55.777 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
09-Sep-2020 11:13:55.790 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
09-Sep-2020 11:13:55.792 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.505 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/8.5.57
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.507 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jun 30 2020 21:49:10 UTC
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.507 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 8.5.57.0
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.507 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Mac OS X
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.507 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.14.6
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.507 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          x86_64
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.507 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.508 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_222-b10
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.508 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            AdoptOpenJDK
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.508 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/mbyousaf/Desktop/Tomcat
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.508 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /Users/mbyousaf/Desktop/Tomcat
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.509 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Users/mbyousaf/Desktop/Tomcat/conf/logging.properties
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.509 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.510 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.510 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.510 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.510 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.511 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/mbyousaf/Desktop/Tomcat
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.511 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Users/mbyousaf/Desktop/Tomcat
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.511 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/Users/mbyousaf/Desktop/Tomcat/temp
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.511 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/mbyousaf/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.590 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.606 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.616 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 377 ms
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.637 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.637 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.57
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.644 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [/Users/mbyousaf/Desktop/Tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/alfresco.xml]
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.689 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet@401b4279]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.initInternal(StandardRoot.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4803)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4939)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:614)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1822)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The directory specified by base and internal path [/Users/mbyousaf/Desktop/Tomcat/../modules/platform]/[] does not exist.
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet.checkType(DirResourceSet.java:257)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractFileResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractFileResourceSet.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet.initInternal(DirResourceSet.java:265)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        ... 16 more
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.690 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error deploying deployment descriptor [/Users/mbyousaf/Desktop/Tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/alfresco.xml]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet@401b4279]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:747)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:614)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1822)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.691 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [/Users/mbyousaf/Desktop/Tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/alfresco.xml] has finished in [47] ms
09-Sep-2020 11:14:10.700 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/Users/mbyousaf/Desktop/Tomcat/webapps/share.war]
09-Sep-2020 11:14:14.846 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
09-Sep-2020 11:14:15.900 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
09-Sep-2020 11:14:15.907 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/share] startup failed due to previous errors
09-Sep-2020 11:14:15.938 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/Users/mbyousaf/Desktop/Tomcat/webapps/share.war] has finished in [5,238] ms
09-Sep-2020 11:14:15.941 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/Users/mbyousaf/Desktop/Tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war]
09-Sep-2020 11:14:15.942 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule.begin [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'debug' to '100' did not find a matching property.
09-Sep-2020 11:14:16.011 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
09-Sep-2020 11:14:16.031 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/Users/mbyousaf/Desktop/Tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war] has finished in [90] ms
09-Sep-2020 11:14:16.033 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/Users/mbyousaf/Desktop/Tomcat/webapps/_vti_bin.war]
09-Sep-2020 11:14:16.199 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
09-Sep-2020 11:14:16.200 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/Users/mbyousaf/Desktop/Tomcat/webapps/_vti_bin.war] has finished in [168] ms
09-Sep-2020 11:14:16.202 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
09-Sep-2020 11:14:16.207 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 5591 ms
```

Below is my alfresco-global.properties file,

```
#
# Set this property unless you have explicitly chosen to expose some repository APIs without authentication
#solr.secureComms=https

#
# Custom content and index data location
#
dir.root=/srv/alfresco/alf_data
dir.keystore=${dir.root}/keystore

#
# Sample database connection properties
db.name=alfresco
db.username=alfresco
db.password=alfresco
db.host=localhost
db.port=5432


#
# Choose DB connection properties for your database, e.g. for PostgreSQL
#
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/alfresco

#
# URL Generation Parameters (The ${localname} token is replaced by the local server name)
#-------------
alfresco.context=alfresco
alfresco.host=${localname}
alfresco.port=8080
alfresco.protocol=http
share.context=share
share.host=${localname}
share.port=8080
share.protocol=http





index.subsystem.name=solr6
solr.secureComms=none
solr.port=8983
```

Comment: Did an `alfresco.log` file get generated? The log posted shows Alfresco failed to start, but not why

Comment: I have checked my logs file on tomcat no alfresco.log file has been generated

Answer (score 1):

The log gives you all the hints in the error stack:

`Error deploying deployment descriptor [/Users/mbyousaf/Desktop/Tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/alfresco.xml`

means you deployment descriptor has an error in the configured module package path:

`The directory specified by base and internal path [/Users/mbyousaf/Desktop/Tomcat/../modules/platform]/[] does not exist.`

So tomcat does not start the deployed war at all.

Comment: My apologies as this is my first time installing the software. Do I go into my tomcat directory and create a folder /modules/platform? As this was not mentioned in the documentation that i was following

Comment: either you remove the deployment descriptor or you create a directory as configured in the deployment descriptor